# Sharpness of the upper bound $(1-x)^n \leq 1 + \frac{nx}{2}$

Tags: inequality, approximation

Here is a known inequality: $$(1-x)^n\leq 1+\frac{nx}{2}\qquad \text{for} \, \frac  1n\leq x\leq 1 $$
I am wondering if there is a better upper bound than this? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to keep [this](http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf) in your bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no such inequality there...

Comment: Reality check: Let $n=4$, $x=\frac12$.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $1+nx/2$. Thank you

Comment: Now we can say $0 < x \leqslant 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leqslant (1-x) < 1 \Rightarrow (1-x)^n \leqslant 1-x$ for $n \geqslant 1$.

Comment: A sharp upper bound, which is asymptotically tight for large $n$: $1/e$.

Comment: The $(0,1)$ Padé approximant of $(1-x)^n$ centered at $x = 1/n$ gives an upper bound:

$$
(1-x)^n \leq \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n (n-1)}{n^2x-1} < \frac{e^{-1} (n-1)}{n^2x-1}.
$$

The proof that this is, in fact, an upper bound is a little tedious so you'll have to forgive its omission.